# How to create beans by condition in xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating the following bean using `xml` config:

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="gate"
    request-channel="input"
    reply-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
    connection-factory="factory"/>
```

How can I configure this based on a condition, eg a value included in application.properties?

I spring 4 I could use `@ConditionalOnExpression("SpEL")`, but how could I achieve the same in xml?

Comment: did you find any solution to it ?

Comment: @NiksVij Not for the xml approach unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Spring Profiles** to conditionally create beans. For e.g.

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="devDatasourceConfig" class="" />
</beans>

<beans profile="production">
    <bean id="productionDatasourceConfig" class=" " />
</beans>
```

You can activate profiles as follows:

**JVM system parameter:**

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

or

**Environment variable:**

```
export spring_profiles_active=dev
```

Comment: I'd prefer to create a condition based on different application properties, not on a fixed profile.